# Mad cursor (SQL Server) make the program freeze and crash

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-cursor

I developed a flight reservation program. I have an (absurd) condition in a trigger that is supposed to execute if it is filled.

My problem is that when I call my stored procedure to book a flight for a customer, my program freezes and crashes due to delay.

I know this problem comes from my trigger, would you have any idea of what is stuck?

If you need more details (tables, stored procedure, code), do not hesitate to tell me! (Sorry for the french comments :p)

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_Check60j]
ON [dbo].[Reservation]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IdVolInsere INT, @DateVol DATETIME, @IdVolExistant INT, @IdClient INT

    SELECT @IdVolInsere = v.VOL_Id 
    FROM Vol v
    JOIN Planning AS p ON p.PLA_Vol_Id = v.VOL_Id
    JOIN inserted AS i ON p.PLA_Id = i.RES_Pla_Id
    WHERE v.VOL_Id = p.PLA_Vol_Id
      AND p.PLA_Id = i.RES_Pla_Id

    SELECT @IdClient = i.RES_Client_Id
    FROM inserted i

    DECLARE @DateVolExistant DATETIME, @DateVolInsere DATETIME;
    DECLARE @IdVilleDepartExistant INT, @IdVilleArriveeExistant INT;
    DECLARE @IdVilleDepartInseree INT, @IdVilleArriveeInseree INT;

        -- Sélectionne l'id des villes du vol inséré
    SELECT @IdVilleDepartInseree = v.VOL_Vil_Depart_Id FROM Vol v WHERE v.VOL_Id = @IdVolInsere
    SELECT @IdVilleArriveeInseree = v.VOL_Vil_Arrivee_Id FROM Vol v WHERE v.VOL_Id = @IdVolInsere

    SELECT @DateVolInsere = p.PLA_Date
    FROM Planning p
    JOIN inserted AS i ON i.RES_Pla_Id = p.PLA_Id
    WHERE i.RES_Pla_Id = p.PLA_Id

    -- Curseur qui compare chaque vol du client existant avec le vol inséré pour vérifier si le vol existant
    -- est un vol retour, si oui, les 2 vols ont-ils plus de 60 jours entre eux? 
    -- Si oui, alors il faut vérifier s'il existe un vol réservé entre ces 2 vols --> S'il y en a un: ERREUR
    DECLARE CR_Check_Vols_Par_Id_Client CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT v.VOL_Id
        FROM Vol v
        JOIN Planning AS p ON v.VOL_Id = p.PLA_Vol_Id
        JOIN Reservation AS r ON p.PLA_Id = r.RES_Pla_Id
        WHERE r.RES_Client_Id = @IdClient

    OPEN CR_Check_Vols_Par_Id_Client

    FETCH CR_Check_Vols_Par_Id_Client INTO @IdVolExistant

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        -- Sélectionne l'id des villes aller (mêmes villes) du dernier vol existant à moins de 60j
        SELECT @IdVilleDepartExistant = v.VOL_Vil_Depart_Id FROM Vol v WHERE v.VOL_Id = @IdVolExistant
        SELECT @IdVilleArriveeExistant = v.VOL_Vil_Arrivee_Id FROM Vol v WHERE v.VOL_Id = @IdVolExistant

            -- Vérifie s'il existe un vol aller pour le vol inséré
        IF (@IdVilleDepartInseree = @IdVilleArriveeExistant) AND (@IdVilleArriveeInseree = @IdVilleDepartExistant)
        BEGIN

            SELECT @DateVolExistant = p.PLA_Date
            FROM Planning p
            JOIN Reservation AS r
            ON r.RES_Pla_Id = p.PLA_Id
            JOIN Vol AS v
            ON p.PLA_Vol_Id = @IdVolExistant
            JOIN inserted AS i
            ON r.RES_Id = i.RES_Id
            WHERE r.RES_Client_Id = @IdClient

            -- Vérifie si le vol inséré est à une date de moins de 60 jours du vol retour existant
            IF ( (DATEDIFF(DAY, @DateVolExistant , @DateVolInsere)) < 60  )
            BEGIN

            DECLARE @CheckVolEntre INT
                -- Sélectionne un vol existant entre le vol aller inséré et le vol retour existant
                SELECT @CheckVolEntre = v.VOL_Id
                FROM Vol v
                JOIN Planning AS p
                ON v.VOL_Id = p.PLA_Vol_Id
                JOIN Reservation AS r
                ON p.PLA_Id = r.RES_Pla_Id
                WHERE r.RES_Client_Id = @IdClient AND v.VOL_Id BETWEEN @IdVolExistant AND @IdVolInsere
                -- Vérifie s'il existe un vol existant entre le vol aller inséré et le vol retour existant
                    IF (@CheckVolEntre != NULL)
                    BEGIN
                        RAISERROR('Réservation impossible', 1, 601)
                        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                        STOP
                END
            END
        END
    END
    CLOSE CR_Check_Vols_Par_Id_Client
    DEALLOCATE CR_Check_Vols_Par_Id_Client
END
```

Thank you in advance!

Jon

Comment: ...even ignoring the cursor, it looks like most of your variables should be retrievable from one query.  Even the cursor appears to be amenable to combining some of the other queries, which is going to help.  My normal suspicion is that the cursor can probably be removed, which **usually** helps (there's a few situations they perform better in), but I'd need to spend a lot more on the analysis...

Comment: Another detail that may or may not be related: you can't use logical comparisons with `NULL`.  The condition at the center of your cursor: `@CheckVolEntre != NULL` will always return `NULL`.  To do that comparison, you have to use `@CheckVolEntre Is Not NULL`

Comment: @Brian Thanks for that, its still not working but it will still help :p

Comment: A **cursor** inside a **trigger** is about the worst thing you can do to kill SQL Server performance..... a trigger is executed in the context and transaction of the statement that caused it to fire, and that transaction will not complete until the trigger is completed. Therefore, triggers *ought to be* extremely nimble, small, fast - everything a **cursor** is **NOT** .......

Comment: JOIN Vol AS v
            ON p.PLA_Vol_Id = @IdVolExistant

--- Don't think you meant that :-)

Comment: @Clay Yes i did, because i need to find the date of the existant flight :-)

Comment: @Korpin - I meant join something as **v** on **p**.something.

Comment: TRIGGERs are meant for working with ROWSETs, not RBAR. Using a CURSOR in a trigger is a big no-no you need to rethink this. I will try to dedicate some time later today to provide an alternate example, in the meantime, I will state that it is possible that you're SELECTs are trying to access data that has been row locked by your trigger--which causes the entire trigger to time out in the end. As a temporary fix, try adding the WITH ( NOLOCK ) hint to your tables involved in your t-sql.

Comment: Stop using cursors, they are horrid.

Comment: @Korpin Hint - you fetch once before you begin your loop. Do you fetch anywhere else? When you correct your code, the first thing you need to do is test it using SSMS and an insert statement that you manually craft. You need to repeat that process for as many possible situations as can be expected. Once you know that the trigger works correctly, then you test the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, even if your trigger wasn't timing out, it almost certainly wasn't doing what you want.  Most of this comes down to the blatant ignoring of possibly multiple return values in some statements.
I'm also a little concerned with what the conditions seem to be getting at, because it looks like I couldn't do something like plan a weekend flight if I had a short business trip the next week!  You might possibly want to be checking the **next** flight, but I don't know enough to guarantee that.

That said, I *think* (based on some assumptions about your data and intentions, but you'll need to check my work) you can make your trigger look like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_Check60j]
ON [dbo].[Reservation]
FOR INSERT -- You could probably do INSTEAD OF and perform the insert here
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT 'Existing Flight'
    FROM Inserted
    JOIN Planning Inserted_planning
      ON Inserted_planning.pla_id = Inserted.res_pla_id
    JOIN Vol Inserted_vol
      ON Inserted_vol.vol_id = Inserted_planning.pla_vol_id
    WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT 'Existing Flight'    
          FROM Vol Return_vol
          JOIN Planning Return_planning
            ON Return_planning.pla_vol_Id = return_vol.vol_id
               AND Return_planning.pla_date >= DATEADD(day, -60, CAST(Inserted_planning.pla_date AS DATE))
               AND Return_planning.pla_id != Inserted_planning.pla_id
          JOIN Return_reservation
            ON Return_reservation.res_pla_id = Return_planning.pla_Id
               AND Return_reservation.res_client_id = Inserted.res_client_id
               AND Return_reservation.res_id != Inserted.res_id
          JOIN Planning Planning_Other
            ON Planning_Other.pla_date >= Return_planning.pla_date
               AND Planning_Other.pla_date < Inserted_planning.pla_date
               AND Planning_other.pla_id != Inserted_planning.pla_id
               AND Planning_other.pla_id != Return_planning.pla_id
          JOIN Reservation Reservation_Other
            ON Reservation_Other.res_pla_id = Planning_Other.pla_id
               AND Reservation_Other.res_client_id = Inserted.res_client_id
               AND Reservation_other.res_id != Inserted.res_id
               AND Reservation_other.res_id != Return_reservation.res_id
          WHERE Return_vol.vol_vil_depart_id = Inserted_vol.vol_vil_arrivee_id
                AND Return_vol.vil_arrivee_id = Inserted_vol.vol_vil_depart_id)


    IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Réservation impossible', 1, 601)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        STOP
    END
END
```

---

Okay, here's the analysis/change reasoning.  Let's break this down by parts.

First off, your pre-cursor queries can be combined and simplified:

```
-- For clarity, put DECLAREs on their own lines
DECLARE @IdVolInsere INT;
DECLARE @IdClient INT;
DECLARE @DateVolInsere DATETIME;
DECLARE @IdVilleDepartInseree INT;
DECLARE @IdVilleArriveeInseree INT;

-- ....I'm against prefixing columns with table names, especially _shortened_ table names.
-- Except maybe for id columns.
SELECT @IdVolInsere = Vol.vol_id, 
       @IdClient = Inserted.res_client_Id,
       @IdVilleDepartInseree = Vol.vol_vil_depart_id,
       @IdVilleArriveeInseree = Vol.vol_vil_arrivee_id,
       @DateVolInsere = Planning.pla_Date
FROM Vol -- Single-character aliases make it hard to track tables.
JOIN Planning 
  ON Planning.pla_vol_Id = vol.vol_Id
JOIN Inserted
  ON Inserted.res_pla_id = Planning.pla_id
```

... now that that's cleared up, let's (clean up and) take a look at the cursor and other statements:

```
DECLARE CR_Check_Vols_Par_Id_Client CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Vol.vol_Id
FROM Vol
JOIN Planning
  ON Planning.pla_vol_Id = Vol.vol_id 
JOIN Reservation
  ON Reservation.res_pla_id = Planning.pla_Id
     AND Reservation.res_client_id = @IdClient
```

...Okay, checking for any `Vol.vol_id` that matches our client id.  Except, this is a straight `AFTER` trigger, we're going to get the row we just inserted!  We probably don't really want that!

Well, we'll ignore that for now, and assume that our end state won't need to worry about it.  Let's just remove the cursor declaration, though, which turns this into a set:

```
SELECT -- dunno what we need yet
FROM Vol
JOIN Planning
  ON Planning.pla_vol_Id = Vol.vol_id 
JOIN Reservation
  ON Reservation.res_pla_id = Planning.pla_Id
     AND Reservation.res_client_id = @IdClient
```

... next the following lines:

```
    -- Sélectionne l'id des villes aller (mêmes villes) du dernier vol existant à moins de 60j
    SELECT @IdVilleDepartExistant = v.VOL_Vil_Depart_Id FROM Vol v WHERE v.VOL_Id = @IdVolExistant
    SELECT @IdVilleArriveeExistant = v.VOL_Vil_Arrivee_Id FROM Vol v WHERE v.VOL_Id = @IdVolExistant

    -- Vérifie s'il existe un vol aller pour le vol inséré
    IF (@IdVilleDepartInseree = @IdVilleArriveeExistant) AND (@IdVilleArriveeInseree = @IdVilleDepartExistant)
```

... tell me we want to restrict our set based on data from the original query.  This will cut the set to just these matching rows.  Let's do that:

```
SELECT -- dunno what we need yet
FROM Vol
JOIN Planning
  ON Planning.pla_vol_Id = Vol.vol_id 
JOIN Reservation
  ON Reservation.res_pla_id = Planning.pla_Id
     AND Reservation.res_client_id = @IdClient
WHERE Vol.vol_vil_depart_id = @IdVilleArriveeInseree
      AND Vol.vil_arrivee_id = @IdVilleDepartInseree
```

... the next query gets data for a simple condition:

```
IF ( (DATEDIFF(DAY, @DateVolExistant , @DateVolInsere)) < 60  )
```

... but again, we already have this data, and can add it to our query:

```
SELECT -- dunno what we need yet
FROM Vol
JOIN Planning
  ON Planning.pla_vol_Id = Vol.vol_id
     AND Planning.pla_date < DATEADD(day, 60, CAST(@DateVolInsere AS DATE))
JOIN Reservation
  ON Reservation.res_pla_id = Planning.pla_Id
     AND Reservation.res_client_id = @IdClient
WHERE Vol.vol_vil_depart_id = @IdVilleArriveeInseree
      AND Vol.vil_arrivee_id = @IdVilleDepartInseree
```

... Unfortunately the primary condition of the next section is most likely nonsense:

```
v.VOL_Id BETWEEN @IdVolExistant AND @IdVolInsere
```

... that's because it assumes a non-key relationship about the key.  If these are auto-generated surrogate keys, that's definitely not true.  The most likely key schemes for a natural key are unlikely to be helpful in all cases.  It's much better to use attribute data, which for this kind of query is usually a date.  My guess is we can use `Planning.pla_date` for this:

```
SELECT -- dunno what we need yet
FROM Vol
JOIN Planning
  ON Planning.pla_vol_Id = Vol.vol_id
     AND Planning.pla_date >= DATEADD(day, -60, CAST(@DateVolInsere AS DATE))
JOIN Reservation
  ON Reservation.res_pla_id = Planning.pla_Id
     AND Reservation.res_client_id = @IdClient
JOIN Planning Planning_Other
  ON Planning_Other.pla_date >= Planning.pla_date
     AND Planning_Other.pla_date < @DateVolInsere
     AND Planning_Other.pla_id != Planning.pla_id
JOIN Reservation Reservation_Other
  ON Reservation_Other.res_pla_id = Planning_Other.pla_id
     AND Reservation_Other.res.client_id = @IdClient
     AND Reservation_Other.res_id != Reservation.res_id
WHERE Vol.vol_vil_depart_id = @IdVilleArriveeInseree
      AND Vol.vil_arrivee_id = @IdVilleDepartInseree
```

... and at this point we observe that we don't actually care about any data, only whether such a row exists.  Thankfully, we can turn that into a regular `EXISTS` clause.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay but i thank you a lot for your answer, it was perfect and i've manage to make it works!

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS ONLY MEANT TO BE A TEMPORARY WORKAROUND. AS STATED IN MY COMMENT, YOU NEED TO REMOVE THE CURSOR FROM YOUR TRIGGER.**

You may be running into locking issues. Try the workaround below and see if that helps. I have also addressed a few coding issues. As stated in a previous comment, you cannot check for NOT NULL with **!=**, it needs to be `IS NOT NULL` or `IS NULL`.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_Check60j]
ON [dbo].[Reservation]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @IdVolInsere INT, @DateVol DATETIME, @IdVolExistant INT, @IdClient INT

    SELECT 
        @IdVolInsere = v.VOL_Id 
    FROM Vol v WITH ( NOLOCK )
    JOIN Planning AS p WITH ( NOLOCK )
        ON p.PLA_Vol_Id = v.VOL_Id
    JOIN inserted AS i 
        ON p.PLA_Id = i.RES_Pla_Id
    WHERE 
        v.VOL_Id = p.PLA_Vol_Id
        AND p.PLA_Id = i.RES_Pla_Id

    SELECT @IdClient = i.RES_Client_Id FROM inserted i;

    DECLARE @DateVolExistant DATETIME, @DateVolInsere DATETIME;
    DECLARE @IdVilleDepartExistant INT, @IdVilleArriveeExistant INT;
    DECLARE @IdVilleDepartInseree INT, @IdVilleArriveeInseree INT;

        -- Sélectionne l'id des villes du vol inséré
    SELECT 
        @IdVilleDepartInseree = v.VOL_Vil_Depart_Id 
        , @IdVilleArriveeInseree = v.VOL_Vil_Arrivee_Id
    FROM Vol v WITH ( NOLOCK )
    WHERE 
        v.VOL_Id = @IdVolInsere;

    SELECT 
        @DateVolInsere = p.PLA_Date
    FROM Planning p WITH ( NOLOCK )
    JOIN inserted AS i 
        ON i.RES_Pla_Id = p.PLA_Id
    WHERE 
        i.RES_Pla_Id = p.PLA_Id

    -- Curseur qui compare chaque vol du client existant avec le vol inséré pour vérifier si le vol existant
    -- est un vol retour, si oui, les 2 vols ont-ils plus de 60 jours entre eux? 
    -- Si oui, alors il faut vérifier s'il existe un vol réservé entre ces 2 vols --> S'il y en a un: ERREUR
    DECLARE CR_Check_Vols_Par_Id_Client CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT 
        v.VOL_Id 
    FROM Vol v WITH ( NOLOCK )
    JOIN Planning AS p WITH ( NOLOCK ) 
        ON v.VOL_Id = p.PLA_Vol_Id
    JOIN Reservation AS r WITH ( NOLOCK ) 
        ON p.PLA_Id = r.RES_Pla_Id
    WHERE 
        r.RES_Client_Id = @IdClient

    OPEN CR_Check_Vols_Par_Id_Client

    FETCH CR_Check_Vols_Par_Id_Client INTO @IdVolExistant

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        -- Sélectionne l'id des villes aller (mêmes villes) du dernier vol existant à moins de 60j
        SELECT 
            @IdVilleDepartExistant = v.VOL_Vil_Depart_Id 
            , @IdVilleArriveeExistant = v.VOL_Vil_Arrivee_Id
        FROM Vol v WITH ( NOLOCK ) 
        WHERE 
            v.VOL_Id = @IdVolExistant;

            -- Vérifie s'il existe un vol aller pour le vol inséré
        IF (@IdVilleDepartInseree = @IdVilleArriveeExistant) AND (@IdVilleArriveeInseree = @IdVilleDepartExistant)
        BEGIN

            SELECT 
                @DateVolExistant = p.PLA_Date
            FROM Planning p WITH ( NOLOCK )
            JOIN Reservation AS r WITH ( NOLOCK )
                ON r.RES_Pla_Id = p.PLA_Id
            JOIN Vol AS v WITH ( NOLOCK )
                ON p.PLA_Vol_Id = @IdVolExistant
            JOIN inserted AS i
                ON r.RES_Id = i.RES_Id
            WHERE 
                r.RES_Client_Id = @IdClient;

            -- Vérifie si le vol inséré est à une date de moins de 60 jours du vol retour existant
            IF ( (DATEDIFF(DAY, @DateVolExistant , @DateVolInsere)) < 60  )
            BEGIN

            DECLARE @CheckVolEntre INT
                -- Sélectionne un vol existant entre le vol aller inséré et le vol retour existant
                SELECT 
                    @CheckVolEntre = v.VOL_Id
                FROM Vol v WITH ( NOLOCK )
                JOIN Planning AS p WITH ( NOLOCK )
                    ON v.VOL_Id = p.PLA_Vol_Id
                JOIN Reservation AS r WITH ( NOLOCK )
                    ON p.PLA_Id = r.RES_Pla_Id
                WHERE 
                    r.RES_Client_Id = @IdClient 
                    AND v.VOL_Id BETWEEN @IdVolExistant AND @IdVolInsere;

                -- Vérifie s'il existe un vol existant entre le vol aller inséré et le vol retour existant
                IF (@CheckVolEntre IS NOT NULL)
                BEGIN
                    RAISERROR('Réservation impossible', 1, 601)
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                    STOP
                END

            END

        END

    END

    CLOSE CR_Check_Vols_Par_Id_Client
    DEALLOCATE CR_Check_Vols_Par_Id_Client

END
```